# How to get the browser to render links in streamed content

Tags: javascript, python, django, streaming

I am using EventSource to get streamed text content in the browser. The problem is that when I want a link to appear even though I have the correct text, the link doesn't render.

This is the text that is outputted (correctly)

```
Here are a few options for single burner camping stoves that you might find suitable:1. The <a href='https://www.bcf.com.au/p/companion-lpg-portable-single-burner-gas-stove/292578.html?cgid=BCF08188'>Companion LPG Portable Single Burner Gas Stove</a> is a great option. It's portable and uses LPG, which is a common fuel type for camping stoves. This makes it a practical choice for camping trips.2. Another good choice is the <a href='https://www.tentworld.com.au/buy-sale/companion-1-burner-wok-cooker-stove'>Companion 1 Burner Wok Cooker Stove</a>. This stove is also portable and has a wok cooker, which adds versatility to your cooking options.For more options, you can check out the range of <a href='https://www.anacondastores.com/camping-hiking/camp-cooking/camping-stoves?q=:relevance:brand:coleman:dealType:OnSale:dealType:CLUB%20PRICE'>Camping Stoves</a> at Anaconda stores. They offer a variety of brands and styles, so you might find other single burner stoves that suit your needs.
```

And here is the html/js:

```
<div id="response-display"></div>
<script>
    const responseDisplay = document.getElementById('response-display');
    const eventSource = new EventSource('http://127.0.0.1:8000/do-chat');

    eventSource.onmessage = function(event) {
        console.log('We have a message');
        console.log(event.data);

        // Append received data to the div
        // responseDisplay.textContent += event.data + "\n";
        responseDisplay.innerHTML += event.data;
    };

    eventSource.onerror = function(error) {
        console.error('EventSource failed:', error);
        eventSource.close();
    };

</script>
```

This is the python/django code:

```
def get_gpt4_streaming_response(self, prompt):
    model_engine = self.MODEL_NAME  
    messages = [{"role": "user", "content": prompt}]
    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model=model_engine,
        messages=messages,
        temperature=0.5,
        max_tokens=1000,  # You can set this to be as long or short as you'd like
        stream=True
    )

    for chunk in response:
        print(chunk)
        yield f"data: {chunk['choices'][0]['delta']['content']}\n\n"

        if chunk['choices'][0]['finish_reason'] == 'stop':
            break
```

Comment: Are you receiving partial html tags from the event source?  Like, can you receive a chunk like `this is a link <a hre` followed by the next chunk giving `f="someurl">click</a>`?  That won’t produce expected output if you append to innerHtml twice.

Comment: Yes the link HTML is broken up like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this modification:

```
const responseDisplay = document.getElementById('response-display');
const eventSource = new EventSource('http://127.0.0.1:8000/do-chat');
let htmlBuffer = "";

eventSource.onmessage = function(event) {
    console.log('We have a message');
    console.log(event.data);
    htmlBuffer += event.data;
    // Append received data as HTML
    responseDisplay.innerHTML = htmlBuffer;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou, this works!

Answer (score 1):

When you set the innerHTML of an element, it treats the content as plain text by default, not as HTML. Therefore, the HTML tags within the received data are displayed as text, and the links are not rendered as actual links.

To render the links correctly, you should use the insertAdjacentHTML method instead of directly setting the innerHTML. Can you check if this works for you?

```
const responseDisplay = document.getElementById('response-display');
const eventSource = new EventSource('http://127.0.0.1:8000/do-chat');

eventSource.onmessage = function(event) {
    console.log('We have a message');
    console.log(event.data);

    // Append received data as HTML
    responseDisplay.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', event.data);
};

eventSource.onerror = function(error) {
    console.error('EventSource failed:', error);
    eventSource.close();
};
```

**EDIT 1:**

**Sanitize HTML**: Use a library like DOMPurify to sanitize and clean the received HTML to remove any potentially malicious or harmful content.
*DOMPurify is designed to sanitize untrusted HTML and make it safe for rendering in a browser.*

First, include DOMPurify in your HTML:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dompurify/2.2.7/purify.min.js"></script>
```

Then, modify your JavaScript code to sanitize and render the HTML:

```
const responseDisplay = document.getElementById('response-display');
const eventSource = new EventSource('http://127.0.0.1:8000/do-chat');

eventSource.onmessage = function(event) {
    console.log('We have a message');
    console.log(event.data);

    // Sanitize and render the received HTML
    const sanitizedHTML = DOMPurify.sanitize(event.data);
    responseDisplay.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', sanitizedHTML);
};

eventSource.onerror = function(error) {
    console.error('EventSource failed:', error);
    eventSource.close();
};
```

This approach ensures that the HTML content is sanitized to remove any potentially harmful elements or scripts before rendering it in the browser.

Also, check if you can implement `Content Security Policy (CSP)`. It allows you to define which sources of content are allowed to be executed on your page, which can help mitigate the risk of XSS attacks.

Comment: Thankyou very much, that makes sense. 
However it's not working, no text or html is rendered but it is being written to console.log() - so the content is returned to the browser. Just not rendering.

Comment: I just noticed this ('beforeend', event.data); so I changed the code to use that. It's printing the text and html, but not rendering the HTML as a clickable link.

Comment: Do you mind providing the skeleton of the HTML text that is printed in the console?

Comment: There are possibilities that the HTML might have `&lt;` for `<` or `&gt;` for `>`. If these entities are present, you should decode them before appending the content to the DOM using JavaScript. Or there might be a `<script>` tag in the text or may be the `Content-Type` header provided by the server is not `text/html`.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into those things. In particular the content type header is text/event-stream ... could that be the issue. Changing it to text/html means nothing gets rendered.

Comment: Might be. Per your query and the code, I understand that you don't have control over the content type. I would suggest that you add some DOMPurify and sanitize the content. I have updated my code. Have a look.

Comment: Thankyou for the suggestion, but I still get the same output i.e. no html rendering.

Comment: Regarding CSP I will read up on it now